# Can a player split up attacks like they can movement?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, attack, multiattack

I didn't think so, but I've read a couple postings elsewhere that make me think otherwise.

Ex. A fighter with 'Extra Attack' from the PHB:

> Beginning at 5th level, you can attack twice, instead of
>   once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn.

To me, both attacks would be during the same attack action, so the fighter could move 10', attack twice, then keep moving, since you can split up movement.

But, could they move, attack once, let's say the opponent goes down, then move to another opponent and use their second attack?

Comment: [Related] [Can you break up your Attack action?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/72888) (but doesn't cover movement) • [Can a creature split up movement more than once?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/78454) (but doesn't ask about splitting attacks from same action)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Your first link answers this one *in the body of the question*. Definitely related!

Answer (score 60):

### Yes, you can!

Look at *Players Handbook p. 190*.

> **Moving between Attacks**
>
> If you take an action that includes more than one weapon attack, you can break up your movement even further by moving between those attacks.

Answer (score 26):

**Yes**, you are able to move in between your attacks.

From the [basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MovingBetweenAttacks) (emphasis added):

> If you take an action that includes more than one weapon attack, **you can break up your movement even further by moving between those attacks.** For example, a fighter who can make two attacks with the Extra Attack feature and who has a speed of 25 feet could move 10 feet, make an attack, move 15 feet, and then attack again.

Answer (score 6):

The easy way to understand the action economy of 5e is to forget other editions.

Treat using your "action" (or "bonus action") on your turn doesn't tie directly to "this is the moment you do it".  Instead act like it grants permission to do the thing, usually whenever you want to on your turn.

You spend those "action tokens" ("bonus action" and "action") to get permission to do the things on your turn.

So on your turn you get to move your speed.  If you spend your action on attack and it comes with extra attacks, you now get to do those attacks.  At any point during your turn.  If you spend your bonus action to get another attack, well, you have another attack you can do on your turn (this additional attack may have timing restrictions).

5e seems to attempt to communicate this through natural language, instead of through gamist language.  This makes it easier to read, but seems to generate this kind of confusion.